# svn user-defined property keyword expansion/substitution

Tags: svn, properties, replace, keyword, substitution

I would like to expand/substitute within a source file a property I've defined.  It would be nice if, within the file, I could use the usual CVS keyword expansion syntax:

`svn propset svn:keywords "Date Revision" "S:\Source\myfile.js"`

`svn propset Originator "me@gmail.com"  "S:\Source\myfile.js"`

On this file:

```
// This is myfile.js
// $Date$
// $Revision$
// $Originator$
```

Yields:

```
// This is myfile.js
// $Date: 2013-08-25 11:22:33 -0600 (Sun, 25 Aug 2013) $
// $Revision: 78 $
// $Originator: me@gmail.com $
```

I'm guessing some kind of commit or post-commit trigger/action could handle this (svn gnubie).  Complication might be that I'm using Google Projects.
NOTE: I know about $Author$.  $Originator$ is just an example of what I'm trying to do.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom keywords in Subversion, you must to use SVN 1.8.* - this version add possibility to define new keywords in addition to old, "classic" svn:keywords. But, anyway, these keywords still can't be fully free-form^ you keyword's definition have to be constructed from limited set of primitives.

From `svn help propset`:

> ```
>   Custom keywords can be defined with a format string separated from
>   the keyword name with '='. Valid format substitutions are:
>     %a   - The author of the revision given by %r.
>     %b   - The basename of the URL of the file.
>     %d   - Short format of the date of the revision given by %r.
>     %D   - Long format of the date of the revision given by %r.
>     %P   - The file's path, relative to the repository root.
>     %r   - The number of the revision which last changed the file.
>     %R   - The URL to the root of the repository.
>     %u   - The URL of the file.
>     %_   - A space (keyword definitions cannot contain a literal space).
>     %%   - A literal '%'.
>     %H   - Equivalent to %P%_%r%_%d%_%a.
>     %I   - Equivalent to %b%_%r%_%d%_%a.
> ```

I.e, you'll, probably, have troubles with constructing `Originator` (in mentioned form) - e-mail of user never directly stored or referenced, but some other keywords may be defined and used

Comment: Thanks.  I should have also mentioned that I had read about the keywords constructed from the limited set of predefined macros.

Comment: .... sorry caught by StackOvfl comment edit timeout.  How about an expansion along the lines of my OP.   My mistake for using the Originator$ / $Author$ as an example.  Start again:  assume a property "xyzzy" with a value of "All your base are belong to us" and I want to expand "$xyzzy$" to "$xyzzy: All your base are belong to us$".  Obviously svn doesn't do it using default functionality.  Can this be done at all using commit automation?  Can I do it on Google Projects?

Comment: @mnemotronic - short answers are "No" and "No". First answer can be "Partially yes, if you can agree with additional commit from ?-commit hook and SVN-server allow to enable and use custom hook (GC *doesn't have* hooks)"

Answer (score 0):

Try simply:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Date Revision Originator=me@gmail.com" "S:\Source\myfile.js"
```

Don't forget to commit the file after setting this property !

(Tested with Tortoise SVN 1.8.11)